# postgresql filter users by age range

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Is there a better way of doing this?
Basically, I have a users table, and on of the columns is birth_date (date)
I am supposed to filter by age range, meaning, I will get a range like 18-24.
This will be passed to a function in a jsonb parameter, as an array of 2 integers.

So I have done the following

```
create or replace function my_filter_function(
    p_search_parameters jsonb
)
returns TABLE(
    user_id bigint,
    birth_date date,
    age interval,
    years double precision
)
  security definer
  language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    return query
    select u.user_id, u.birth_date, age(u.birth_date), date_part('year', age(u.birth_date))
    from users u
    where u.birth_date is not null
        and ( (p_search_parameters#>>'{age,0}') is null or u.birth_date <= (now() - ((p_search_parameters#>>'{age,0}')::integer * interval '1 year'))::date)
        and ( (p_search_parameters#>>'{age,1}') is null or u.birth_date >= (now() - ((p_search_parameters#>>'{age,1}')::integer * interval '1 year'))::date)
    ;

end;
$$;
```

-- this is just a aluttle helpder function to better post and explain the question
This seems to be doing the job, but was hoping to find other ways of doing this while still getting a jsonb parameter, array of 2 integers

Any ideas?

Comment: "*This will be passed to a function in a jsonb parameter, as an array of 2 integers.*" - why so complicated? Better declare your function with two integer parameters.

Comment: or use two variables, `age_from integer := (p_search_parameters#>>'{age,0}')::integer` and `age_to := (p_search_parameters#>>'{age,1}')::integer`.

Comment: well, it's an inherited function, that is huge, and it has a jsonb parameter, and all search parameters (over 30 different params) are sent through this jsonb object. I suppose it's because it's easier to add new parameters this way.:)

Still have not found a more efficient way than what I already did, but the function works correct with the new filter, so I am happy with it.

Just now realised what Stefanov suggested, to still use the jsonb parameter, but to put the passed filters into variables and use the variables. Nice suggestion Stefanov

Comment: Ah so this is only a part of your function, not the actual code. You should've made that clear - but you can still [edit] your question to clarify

Comment: yes, i made a little helper function for the sake of the question :) will do